# Convert inputDecorationTheme to InputDecoration in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am writing a [`FormBuilderField`](https://github.com/danvick/flutter_form_builder) extension that gets all of its decoration properties out of main `ThemeObject` except for `hintText` property which I want to be able to pass manually.

The main problem, from my point of you, is the following: the `themeObject` contains only `InputDecorationTheme`'s instance which doesn't have `hintText` property, so I decide to create `InputDecoration` by casting `InputDecorationTheme`'s instance to `InputDecoration` and then use `copyWith` method to inject the missing property. You can see the code sample below.

```dart
class MyNewAwsomeField extends FormBuilderField<String>{
# code that gets the theme object out of context (with is working fine)
static final theme = getThemeData();

MyNewAwsomeField ({
   Key? key,
   required String name,
   required String hintText,
   ValueChanged<String?>? onChanged,
}) : super(
   key:key,
   decoration: (theme.inputDecorationTheme as InputDecoration).copyWith(
   hintText: hintText,
   onChange: onChange,
   name:name
 )
}
```

The error I get says literary "Expected a value of type 'InputDecoration', but got one of type 'InputDecorationTheme' ...". I understand the error, so I would like to know is there a way to get `InputDecoration`'s instance out of `InputDecorationTheme` one and add to it a custom properties?

Would glad to hear any piece advice.

Answer (score 8):

I believe when instantiating `InputDecoration` it will automatically inherit all properties from `InputDecorationTheme`. If that's not the case then you can use [applyDefaults](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/applyDefaults.html) method from `InputDecoration` to apply properties from `InputDecorationTheme` to your `InputDecoration` object.

```dart
const decoration = InputDecoration();

final decorationWithThemeProperties = decoration.applyDefaults(const InputDecorationTheme(
  filled: true,
  fillColor: Colors.red,
));
// or
// final decorationWithThemeProperties = decoration.applyDefaults(Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme);

return TextField(
  decoration: decorationWithThemeProperties,
);
```

In your case it would be:

```dart
class MyNewAwsomeField extends FormBuilderField<String>{
  // code that gets the theme object out of context (with is working fine)
  static final theme = getThemeData();

  MyNewAwsomeField ({
    Key? key,
    required String name,
    required String hintText,
    ValueChanged<String?>? onChanged,
  }) : super(
    key:key,
    decoration: (const InputDecoration()).applyDefaults(theme.inputDecorationTheme).copyWith(
      hintText: hintText,
      onChange: onChange,
      name: name
    )
  }

  ...
}
```